# Creating sms intent does not prompt the user the option to use their sms app. Galaxy s5. Any thoughts?

Tags: android

I have tried two different code methods, both sadly produce the same result.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Sick of waiting in line? Download Slydde here: " + url);
startActivity(sendIntent);


Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

The goal of this code is to promt the user to choose one of their messenger apps. I would like them to be able to choose their preference. Google Messenger, Verizon Messenger, their phone's system messenger.. w.e. they want.

The code above does accomplish that but...

**The issue here is that the intent starts, and the user does not have the option to select their default sms app most of the time.**

For example, one of my users has a galaxy s5 with samsung messenger and verizon messenger. When they press the button to execute this code, their phone does not give them any sms options. Only email app options. On other phone types, Moto, LG, I have not experienced this issue.

verizon messenger works fine with this code on my motorola MotoX, and verizon messenger works with LG V10

Comment: Um, what are you expecting to happen with either of those? If you are trying to send a message, use `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO`.

Comment: the code I posted prompts the user to choose an app to share the message, so there sms app would be chosen. The whole point of viewing rather then sending is so they can fill in the destination

Comment: `ACTION_SEND` allows them to fill in a destination.

Comment: ACTION_SEND is not producing anything for me. I substituted it in for ACTION_VIEW

Comment: Plain `ACTION_SEND` does not use a `Uri`. `ACTION_SENDTO` works with an `smsto:` `Uri`.

Comment: For now I am going to use ACTION_SENDTO, substituted in for ACTION_VIEW, because it allows the user to input the destination. The messenger app theme that opens inside of my application is the generic system messenger app though. When I use ACtion_VIEW, the user can choose what app they want to use to send the messege. That is ultimately what I want, but for most users, their messenger app doesn't show up in the list